# ¿Por qué no funciona este programa?

Tags: c

Imaginemos tener **dos documentos de texto**: *entrada.txt* y *salida.txt*. El contenido del segundo es vacío y el del primero es:

En algún de la Mancha

de cuyo nombre no quiero acordarme

vivía un hidalgo

de nombre don Quijote

**Lo que queremos hacer es copiar el mismo texto de *entrada.txt* en *salida.txt*, pero ampliando los espacios en blanco** entre las palabras de cada línea (sin expandir los saltos de línea). Podemos dar por hecho que la longitud de las líneas de *entrada.txt* no superan los 80 caracteres, contando con el salto de línea.

El archivo *entrada.txt* se introducirá por entrada estándar, así como *salida.txt* será salida estándar. El número de espacios en blanco entre palabras será argv[1]. Así, un **ejemplo del llamada** sería *./programa 3 < entrada.txt > salida.txt*

Para resolver este ejercicio, yo propongo este **código**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

        if(argc != 2){
                return 1;
        }
        else{
                int espaciado = atoi(argv[1]);
                int maxLinea = 80;
                char linea[maxLinea];
                char *palabra; palabra = malloc(maxLinea*sizeof(char));
                char anadir[espaciado];/*Espacio en blanco que debemos anadir*/

                int i = 0;
                for(; i < espaciado; i++){
                        anadir[i] = ' ';
                }

                while(!feof(stdin)){
                        fgets(linea,maxLinea,stdin);/*Cogemos una línea*/
                        char delimitador[] = " ";
                        palabra = strtok(linea,delimitador);/*Cogemos palabra a palabra cada línea*/
                        while(palabra != NULL){
                                fputs( strcat(palabra,anadir) , stdout);
                                palabra = strtok(linea,delimitador);
                        }
                }
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Sin embargo, **no hace nada de nada**. El documento *salida.txt* queda vacío. ¿Qué está fallando?

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El primer problema que encontramos es que el array `anadir` está mal inicializado:

```
char anadir[espaciado];/*Espacio en blanco que debemos anadir*/

int i = 0;
for(; i < espaciado; i++){
        anadir[i] = ' ';
}
```

En C, las cadenas de caracteres deben terminar **siempre** con `\0`. Las funciones que manipulan cadenas en C se basan en esta premisa. Tu cadena no cumple este requisito, por lo que la llamada a `strcat` provocará que se copien en el buffer caracteres no deseados (hasta que el programa encuentre un `\0` en algún sitio).

```
char anadir[espaciado+1];

// opcion 1
for(int i=0; i < espaciado; i++){
    anadir[i] = ' ';
}
anadir[espaciado] = '\0';

// opcion 2
sprintf(anadir, "%*c", espaciado, ' ');
```

Por otro lado, la función `strtok` obra su magia **modificando** la cadena de caracteres original. Lo que hace es reemplazar el delimitador por un finalizador de cadena `\0`.

Posteriormente llamas a `strcat` y esta función añadirá el contenido de `anadir` al final de `linea`, es decir, donde antes se encontraba el espacio ... y machacando de paso lo que haya más allá de dicho espacio.

Un ejemplo para verlo más claro:

```
                         00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0a 0b 0c 0d 0e 0f
linea antes de strtok ->  E  n     a  l  g  u  n     d  e  l  a     M  a
linea tras strtok     ->  E  n \0  a  l  g  u  n     d  e  l  a     M  a
linea tras strcat     ->  E  n           g  u  n     d  e  l  a     M  a
```

Como ves, estás perdiendo información y no es lo que quieres.

Otro error que tienes es la comprobación de `feof`:

```
while(!feof(stdin)){
    fgets(linea,maxLinea,stdin);/*Cogemos una línea*/
```

El flag `feof` se activa tras la primera lectura incorrecta, es decir, el chequeo de `feof` debe hacerse inmediatamente después de llamar a `fgets`, no antes.

Yo el ejercicio lo plantearía de otra manera:

- Leería caracter a caracter
- Imprimes el caracter leido
- Compruebas si es un espacio, si lo es y el caracter anterior no era un espacio, añades los nuevos separadores

Con código, sería algo así:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int numEspacios = atoi(argv[1]);
    int esPalabra = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        char c = getchar();
        if (feof(stdin)) break;
        
        putchar(c);
        if (c == ' ')
        {
            if (esPalabra == 1)
            {
                esPalabra = 0;
                for (int i=0; i<numEspacios; i++)
                {
                    putchar(' ');
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            esPalabra = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Funciona perfectamente. Gracias por una respuesta tan completa y clara.